# Link to a Media entity file from text editor

Tags: 8, media

The idea is to create an hyperlink on some arbitrary text typed in CK Editor. That link should target a file uploaded to a Media file entity.

[Media entity download filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/medf) already makes it possible but it has to be done in two separated steps (create the media entity+upload that file then create the link via [Linkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit)).

An acceptable flow could be :

- type some text and select it
- click a toolbar button (my first thought was entity embed)
- select an existing Media File or create/upload it
- save to generate the link

It's (almost) doable via a combination of [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser), [Entity Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) and [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) but that will output the Entity itself (displayed with a specific view mode).

Is it possible to achieve something similar with or without an existing contrib module from the [Media ecosystem](https://github.com/drupal-media/d8-guide/blob/master/modules/media/intro.md) ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @leymannx I updated my question, I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Why not just use LinkIt?

Comment: @Kevin For the reason I explained above, it has to be done in two separated steps if you want to add a new file. This is a viable solution for a small-sized website with educated authors but not optimal in other cases.